# Converting a sequence of bytes into proper characters

Tags: perl, utf-8

I use this [site](https://software.hixie.ch/utilities/cgi/unicode-decoder/utf8-decoder) to convert sequence of bytes like this:

Ð Ð°Ð±Ñ‹Ð½Ð¸

into proper character sequences like this:

Рабыни

It seems that the site decodes the UTF8 sequences into their original characters. For some reason, some of my files names are corrupted and I need to convert them back to their original.

Since number of files is not less, I decided to write a perl script for this purpose. I tried this

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use utf8;
$str = "Ð Ð°Ð±Ñ‹Ð½Ð¸.avi";
utf8::decode($str);
binmode STDOUT, ":utf8";
print "$str\n";
```

as a test on one file name. When running the script, I redirect the output to a file. When I see the content of the file, I see that the content is the same as the input string and no conversion is made. This is while the output is consistent to what the site converts for sequences like this:

Ð°Ð½Ð³ÐµÐ»Ð¾Ð²

I tried running the script on both Linux (Ubuntu) and Windows by using ActivePerl and both give the same result. Concentrating on Windows, what do you think to be the error of the script?

Thanks

Comment: Your sample text is incomplete, I'm getting "� абыни.avi". Also, check if your terminal supports UTF-8

Comment: I didn't find what you meant by saying that my sample test is incomplete. what sample text you meant? I tried redirecting output to a file. I tried also linux. none seem to work.

Comment: If I copy-and-paste your script into my linux terminal, I see the Cyrillic text. So I think this must be a windows support thing.

Comment: yes, ur right. in cmd.exe, i can't see cyrillic texts as they should be shown. but as far as the output is redirected to a file, the terminal is not dependent. the terminal just used to run the perl script. but even in this case, the output file includes the same input.

Comment: use Encode;
$str = "Ð°Ð½Ð³ÐµÐ»Ð¾Ð².avi";
$str = decode('utf8',$str);

open(H,'>','pradeep.txt');
print H $str;
close H;
This works for me.

Comment: yes, it does. but it still doesn't work for Ð°Ð±Ñ‹Ð½Ð¸

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encoding `Рабыни` using UTF-8 gives `D0.A0.D0.B0.D0.B1.D1.8B.D0.BD.D0.B8`.

However, `Ð Ð°Ð±Ñ‹Ð½Ð¸` is `D0.20.D0.B0.D0.B1.D1.2039.D0.BD.D0.B8`.

The main problem is that `utf8::decode($str);` is failing because `Ð Ð°Ð±Ñ‹Ð½Ð¸` isn't valid UTF-8. The encoding of `Рабыни` has been irreversibly corrupted.

---

As for Windows,

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

my $terminal_enc_layer;
BEGIN {
    $terminal_enc_layer = $^O eq 'MSWin32'
        ? do { require Win32; ":encoding(cp".Win32::GetACP().")" }
        : ":locale";
}

use utf8;
use open ':std', $terminal_enc_layer;

use strict;
use warnings;

my $str = "\xD0\xA0\xD0\xB0\xD0\xB1\xD1\x8B\xD0\xBD\xD0\xB8";

utf8::decode($str)
   or die "Bad data";

print "$str\n";
```